# how use omnipay for paypale payement in Laravel 5.4

Tags: paypal-sandbox, laravel-5.4, omnipay

Please how i can make an checkout throw paypal from my website,
using Sabdbox & omnipay  package,
i'm using Laravel 5.4
i installed the omnipay package
and i created my sandbox account
please HELP

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Omnipay is yet compatible with Laravel 5.4 because of the Symfony 3 dependency.  Either go back to an earlier version of Laravel or wait for Omnipay 3.0.

It might help for you to show the code that you currently have so we can comment on that.  If you look in the class docblocks for PayPal_Rest gateway in Omnipay you will see some usage examples as well as sample code.